# Finding the count of '1' in string array in C

Tags: c, for-loop, char, find, c-strings

I was doing some homework and I need to make a program in C which counts how many times '1' is in the string array. For example I got string array and in it I got 3 strings: D12, B11 and F1.

The program needs to count all of the '1'. For this example that would be 4. How do I accomplish that?

Here is the code that I have so far:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    int i=0,N,br=0;
    char s[10][20];

    scanf("%d", &N);
    for(i=0;i<N;i++)
    {
       scanf("%s", &s[i]);
       if(strchr(s[i], '1') != NULL);
       {
           ++br;
       }
    }
    printf("%d", br);
}
```

Comment: Tip: Walk through the string with a pointer and count all that match `'1'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should substitute this if statement

```
   if(strchr(s[i], '1') != NULL);
   {
       ++br;
   }
```

for the following loop

```
   for ( const char *p = s[i]; ( p = strchr( p, '1' ) ) != NULL; ++p )
   {
       ++br;
   }
```

Pay attention to that this call

```
scanf("%s", &s[i]);
```

must be changed at least like

```
scanf("%s", s[i]);
```

Comment: Well this makes sense,but the compiler shows me this error now that i changed the if to for: [Error] 'for' loop initial declarations are only allowed in C99 or C11 mode
i don't know what should i do now

Comment: @Sh4dy It seems you are using an old compiler or you should change options of the compiler. Place  the declaration of the pointer before the loop like const char *p = s[i]; for ( ; ( p = strchr( p, '1' ) ) != NULL; ++p )

Comment: Yeah, thanks that works. How can i do the same thing without strchr?

Comment: @Sh4dy in this case you in any case need to use a loop. for example int j = 0; for ( ; s[i][j] != '\0'; j++ ) { if ( s[i][j] == '1' ) ++br; }

Answer (score 0):

Just write the function counting occurrences of the char in one string.

```
size_t count(const char *str, int ch)
{
    size_t cnt = 0;

    while(*str) cnt += (*str++ == ch);

    return cnt;
}
```